# Regex before word not starting with specific characters

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I dont want to match that specific words `may|may15`, doesnt starting with specific chars `x|-|+`

> TRADED; Mar15 x May15, 5 MW Base 121,50 TL

Examples:

```
x May15 > WRONG
- May15 > WRONG
+ May15 > WRONG
xMay15  > WRONG
-May15  > WRONG
+May15  > WRONG
May15   > TRUE
May15,  > TRUE
May15 + > FALSE
May15 x > FALSE
etc...
```

I tried following but it matches:

```
(?<!-)\b(?![x|\-|\+]\s?)(may|may15)(?!\s[x|\-|\+])\b(?!-)(\s|\,)
```

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/eV3kW3/1

Chars are static: `+` `-` and `+`

But words are dynamic and these are all months:

> jan|jan13|jan-13|ocak 2013|oca 2013|ocak 13|oca 13
>
> feb|feb13|feb-13|şubat 2013|şub 2013|şubat 13|şub 13
>
> etc..

Comment: Which lang you're running?

Comment: So whats your expected output?

Comment: I just want "not match".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be possible through the PCRE verb `(*SKIP)(*F)`

```
[-x+]\h*may(?:15)?(*SKIP)(*F)|may(?:15)?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eV3kW3/3)

At first, `[-x+]\h*may(?:15)?` matches all the `may` strings you want to exclude. Then the following `(*SKIP)(*F)` part makes the match to fail. Now, the regex engine uses the pattern which was next to the `|` operator to match characters from the remaining part of the string. `\h*` matches zero or more horizontal whitespace characters.

**Update:**

```
(?:[-x+]\h*may(?:15)?|may(?:15)?\h*[-x+])(*SKIP)(*F)|may(?:15)?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eV3kW3/5)

Comment: Actually, i hard to understand your code :). Your answer is perfect but my chars are static and words are dynamic. How can i implement these words? `may|may15` is just a sample. Updating the question now with words.

Comment: @Bora you actually used `may15`, `may` strings in your regex. That's why i came up with the above which uses `may` substring. What's your expected output for the updated one? Please try to ask the exact question at ver first.

Comment: Can you check out please? https://regex101.com/r/uY9mB3/2 For example `jul|jul-15` word. We set `-+x` chars that do not come after word. But `jul-15` have the `-` sign. Although word true but  its not match. Thx

Comment: According to your answer, i have to define whole words like `jul(?:[-+x]15)`. I solved the issue with another way, thx.

Answer (score 1):

```
[x+-]\s*(?:may15|may)\K|(?:may15|may)\s*[x+-]\K|(?:may15|may)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/127

Comment: Your pattern works great, thx for helps.. @AvinashRaj answer little best for me ;)